# поиск выражения даты в тексте после указанной фразы на русском

Tags: python, дата, парсер

Доброго дня.

Есть переменная с текстом: "Дискотеки Москвы: анонс на 1 ноября". 
Текст может меняться, неизменным остается только фраза "анонс на" и далее следует <день> <месяц>

Не подскажите, как мне, после нахождения ключевой фразы, спарсить следующие четыре слова?

Comment: *анонс на* - это ключевая фраза? тогда *1 ноября* - это не 4 слова

Comment: Да, "анонс на" -это ключевая фраза.
4 слова, включая анонс на. То есть "Анонс на 1 ноября" мне надо вычленить в переменную.

Comment: связанный вопрос: [Parse French date in python](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26294333/4279)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы достать `date` объект после указанной фразы, можно использовать регулярные выражения и [`dateparser` модуль, чтобы саму дату распознать в date-объект](https://dateparser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#usage):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals
import re
import dateparser # $ pip install dateparser

text = "Дискотеки Москвы: анонс на 1 ноября"
m = re.search(r"{phrase}\s+(\w+\s+\w+)".format(phrase=re.escape("анонс на")), text,
              flags=re.UNICODE)
date_string = m.group(1)
print(dateparser.parse(date_string).date())
# -> 2016-11-01
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ.  
Не помогло. Использую python 2
`    text = answer['response'][i]['description']
    text = text.lower()  
    m = re.search(r"{phrase}\s+(\w+\s+\w+)".format(phrase=re.escape("анонс на")), text)  
    date_string = m.group(1)  
    print dateparser.parse(date_string).date()`  
Хотя текст в переменной text:  
`анонс на 28 октября (пятница 20.30-23.55)`

Comment: @jsf спасибо, помогло.
P.S. Я вроде адаптирую  код для 2 питона. Видимо, где-то что-то пропустил.

Answer (score 0):

Используйте для этого регулярные выражения. Например:

```
text = """
Дискотеки Москвы: анонс на 1 ноября
Дискотеки Москвы: анонс на 1 декабря
Дискотеки СПб: анонс на 10 декабря
Дискотеки СПб: анонс на 26 декабря
"""

import re
for date, month in re.findall('анонс на (\d+) (\w+)', text):
    print(date, month)
```

Консоль:

```
1 ноября
1 декабря
10 декабря
26 декабря
```

---

Для одиночного выражения можно использовать метод [search](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.search):

```
text = "Дискотеки Москвы: анонс на 1 ноября"

import re
match = re.search('анонс на (\d+) (\w+)', text)
if match:
    date = match.group(1)
    month = match.group(2)
    print(date, month)  #  1 ноября
```

**PS.**

Примеры на `Python 3`. Для `Python 2` нужно импортировать функцию `print`: `from __future__ import print_function`, или использовать одноименный оператор `print`.

Comment: Спасибо, но находить совпадения он не хочет/

Код
    `text = answer['response'][0]['description']#в answer ответ json, текст существует
    text = text.lower()
    match = re.findall(u' анонс на (\d+) (\w+)',text)
    print match`
Возвращает пустой массив.
Хотя в тексте присутствует искомый текст:
` анонс на 28 октября (пятница 20.30-23.55)`

Comment: У меня ваш текст распарсился, попробуйте добавить `u'анонс на (\d+) (\w+)'`. А лучше также к вашему вопросу, в конце укажите версию питона и запрос, по которому возвращаются данные